# PostgreSQL - Select columns with changed value optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a history table with like 20 columns and I need to know what column and value were changed. I did this query:

```
   (SELECT id, rev, col1 as "val", CASE WHEN TRUE THEN 'col1'END "field"
      FROM ( SELECT id, col1, rev, LAG(col1) 
               OVER (ORDER BY rev) AS prev_col1
               FROM my_table ) x
     WHERE id = 82
       AND col1 <> COALESCE(prev_col1, col1)
  ORDER BY rev)
     UNION  
    (SELECT id, rev, col2 as "val",
  CASE WHEN TRUE THEN 'col2'END "field"
       FROM ( SELECT id, col2, rev, LAG(col2) 
                OVER (ORDER BY rev) AS prev_col2
                FROM my_table ) x
      WHERE id = 82
        AND col2 <> COALESCE(prev_col2, col2)
   ORDER BY rev)
      UNION ....
```

I would like to known a better way to do this. It works, but it doesn't look very well.

**Edit**

I had to change to change the SQL answer from Gordon a little to work:

```
  select id, rev, field, val
    from (select v.*,
                 lag(v.val) over (partition by v.id, v.field order by v.rev) as prev_val
          from ((select t.id, t.rev, 'col1' field, col1 val from my_table t) union all
                (select t.id, t.rev, 'col2' field, col2 val from my_table t) union all
                 . . .
               ) v
          where v.id = 82
         ) tv
    where prev_val <> val or prev_val is null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to unpivot the rows.  You could rephrase the query without using `union all`.  The following does a lateral join for the unpivot and expresses the logic in a single `select` clause:

```
select id, rev, field, val
from (select t.id, t.rev, v.field, v.val,
             lag(v.val) over (partition by t.id, v.field order by t.rev) as prev_val
      from my_table t, lateral
           (values ('col1', col1),
                   ('col2', col2),
                   . . .
           ) v(field, val)
      where t.id = 82
     ) tv
where prev_val <> val or prev_val is null;
```

Lateral joins were introduced in Postgres 9.3.  An alternative is to explicitly unpivot:

```
select id, rev, field, val
from (select t.*,
             lag(v.val) over (partition by t.id, v.field order by t.rev) as prev_val
      from ((select t.id, t.rev, 'col1', col1 from my_table t
            ) union all
            (select t.id, t.rev, 'col2', col2 from my_table t
            ) union all
             . . .
           ) t
      where t.id = 82
     ) tv
where prev_val <> val or prev_val is null;
```